# Disable of mat-form-field in template-driven form

Tags: angular

I developed a template-driven form in which I used input fields such as `mat-input`, `mat-select`, `mat-datepicker` and `mat-select`.

Each of them embedded in a `mat-field-form`. I want to disable them based on a condition. I think if I disable the `mat-field-form`, all of them would be disabled, or, as each of inputs `atrr.disable` to be disabled?

Is it OK to do this? On the other hand, I used `#actionsForm="ngForm"` to 'required' them, but only `mat-input` works and other inputs do not listen to 'required'.

Any leads, please.

Comment: could you provide a little demo in stackblitz.com or some code here, that will help

Answer (score 1):

In `.html` use`[disabled]` attribute like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [disabled]="isDisabled"></input>    
    <textarea matInput [disabled]="isDisabled"></textarea> 
</mat-form-field>
```

In `.ts` set `isDisabled` variable `true` or `false` as per condition:

```js
//do something like variable declaration and condition checking

this.isDisabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll apply your recommend as soon as possible and inform you the result.

Comment: sorry, I applied attr. [disabled]="cond" and got an error: the mat-form-field has not [disabled] input!

Comment: It's my bad! yes, `mat-form-field` has not `[disabled]` attribute. So, you have to use `[disabled]` attribute with the, for example, matInput inside `mat-form-field`. Answer is edited whatsoever, not sure whether this meet your requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, does it work for mat-select, text-area and datepicker? How about mat-select, textarea and datepicker?

Comment: Its a question for me, the textarea, datepicker and select elements which can be key elements for a form, don't work with attr.required! Can you answer it?

Comment: `mat-select`, `textarea` and `mat-datepicker` all these work fine with `[disabled]` attribute